# What is the difference between the thread in CPU (hardware) and those in thread pool

Tags: multithreading, cpu, threadpool

People always call CPU has 4 cores & 8 threads or 2 cores & 2 threads, etc.

But in the thread pool, there are quite a lot of tiny threads generated, are these related to the hardware `threads`?

I am thinking if the CPU threads are actually `processes`.

Also, I think the actual thread is just a block of code that runs while loop and execute available task otherwise sleep, is this statement correct?

Comment: The question is not specific enough with language and OS tags missing.  But in general there is no difference, a threadpool thread is just a wee bit different in that it never quits.  The threadpool manager uses a producer/consumer algorithm to get those threads to execute work.  Yes, a while loop on the tp thread.  No sleep, the thread simply waits for work with, typically, a monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the hardware side the CPU has cores, cores have 1-8 schedulable threads, new Power-CPUs have up to 8 threads, Knightbridge(?) has 4, most other desktop CPU's have 2, older and/or smaller CPU's got 1.

On the software side a program can have multiple processes (different virtual memory mapping), a process can multiple software threads (sharing the processes memory map), a software thread is the scheduling partner for the hardware thread.

Then you again can have a logical thread in software, often called a fiber, which is a user software scheduled mini thread run by a software thread.

Comment: what's the relationship between the hardware threads and software side processes?

Comment: @TonyLin, no direct, a thread in a process must have a hardware thread to run on.